# creating text file in wp7 using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have tried following code:

```
imports system.io

imports system.io.isolatedstorage 

private sub Button_Click(sender as system.object, e as system.windows.routedeventargs) handles button1.click

dim isoStore As IsolatedStorageFile = isolatedstoragefile.getuserstoreforapplication
isostore.createfile("c:\test.txt")

end sub
```

when i run the code on windows phone emulator it shows exception "Operation not permitted on isolatedstoragefilestream"

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone is not like a PC operating system, there is **no** C:\ - each app has it's own contained area where you store and access files, hence the name `IsolatedStorage`.

[GeekChamp has a great tutorial on `IsolatedStorage`](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/all-about-wp7-isolated-storage-read-and-save-text-files), which is in C#.

For VB.Net, the following code sample should help you getting started with `IsolatedStorage`:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/VBWP8ImageFromIsolatedStora-11071695